# How to get dropdown option value using dropdown option in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc

I am developing framework for selenium automation and I have got stuck to get the dropdown option's value using dropdown. I have dropdown option but now I want the value of same dropdown. Is it possible to get it in selenium.

For example:

Here is the Html tag:

```
    <select id="periodId" name="period" style="display: none;">
    <option value="week1">1</option>
    <option value="week2">2</option>
    <option value="week3">3</option>
    <option value="week4">4</option>
    <option value="week5">5</option>
    <option value="week16">6</option>
    </select>
```

Now in the framework which I have developed, I will pass the dropdown option '5', now I want the value of dropdown option '5'. Is that possible to get value 'week5' for dropdown option '5' using selenium?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this and let me know.

```
Select period = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("periodId")));

period.selectByVisibleText("5");

String value = period.getFirstSelectedOption().getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, it is working as expected with your sample code :)